# Trigger that modifies multiple rows on diffrent table then it was invoked on in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have tried to perform update on table which was trigger by update on other table and I got error message:

The row value(s) updated or deleted either do not make the row unique or they alter multiple rows.

For example I have this tables:

```
table_1
===========
int id   (primary_key,identity)
nchar(10)  state_name

table_2
===========
int number
```

And after updating table_2 I want to change all values in column 'state_name' to 'false'

```
create trigger tr on table_2
after update
as
update table_1 set state_name = 'false'
```

And when I try to update table_2 I receive error message.
Is there a way to walk around this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create table table_1(id int identity(1,1) primary key, state_name char(10))

create table table_2 ( number int)
go

create trigger tr on table_2 after update as update table_1 set state_name = 'false'
go

insert table_1 select 'true'
insert table_2 select 1

go

update table_2 set number = 2

select * from table_1

select * from table_2

Which version do you use? It worked out nicely in SQL 2K8 & SQL 2K5. Check your code again.

Comment: It works fine as long as you have distinct records in table_2. Try to add more 1s in it.

I have seen it in past.

Comment: I use SQL 2K5. You are right this works!
It's interesting because I got this error message while editing records with Sql Server Managment Studio   table_2 ->Open table  and after changing record I couldn't commit it.
I wonder why.

Comment: What's more when I add column with primary key to table_2 it works when I edit records this way table_2->Open table
It must be some kind Sql Server Management Studio limitation.

Comment: >>It must be some kind Sql Server Management Studio limitation.
Try avoiding the SSMS for these activities. SSMS is known for many bugs and its best done using TSQL.

Answer (score 2):

Add a primary key constraint in Table_2 (for example an auto inc no) and you will be fine.