# SQL Server Update Trigger (Not Unique Insert Issue)

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a super simple table that looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
[SomeColumn] [int] NOT NULL )
```

I also have a super simple trigger on another table that looks something like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Audit_TableXYZ] ON [dbo].[TableXYZ] AFTER UPDATE

AS

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] Values (123)
```

My problem is that when the trigger runs I get the following error:

***The row value(s) updated or deleted either do not make the row unique or they alter multiple rows (2 rows).***

I don't get it, why would I get this error?

Thank you.

Comment: does the trigger really contain the value '123' ?

Comment: Yes, I just hardcoded the value to 123 to keep the trigger as simple as it could possibly be.  I make sure that the "TestTable" has zero rows when I run the trigger and I only update a single cell on table that has the trigger. Even if I remove the primary key constrain I still get the same error (just tried that, I will update the post).

Comment: Do you use MSSMS to edit the rows in `TableXYZ`? Similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901931/trigger-that-modifies-multiple-rows-on-diffrent-table-then-it-was-invoked-on-in-s. Turns out to be problems with duplicate rows when editing with MSSMS but works just fine when updating is done in code. You need a primary key in `TableXYZ`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the top of the trigger definition. This will suppress the additional rows affected message that emanates from the trigger and confuses SSMS.

i.e.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Audit_TableXYZ] 
ON [dbo].[TableXYZ] 
AFTER UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
--Rest of trigger definition follows
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] Values (123)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't recreate. Is this conflicting with some other trigger or a constraint or something, maybe? I don't know.

**Update:**

As Mikael said, adding a primary key in TableXYZ will work-around the issue. Only happens when you are modifying the table with SSMS. Thanks Mikael. This works:

```
create database testdb
go
use testdb

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
[SomeColumn] [int] NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableXYZ](
[ID] [int] identity(1,1) primary key,
[SomeColumn] [int] NOT NULL )
go

create TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Audit_TableXYZ] ON [dbo].[TableXYZ] AFTER UPDATE
AS
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] Values (123)
go

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Tablexyz] Values (4)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Tablexyz] Values (5)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Tablexyz] Values (6)

update tablexyz set somecolumn = 789
update tablexyz set somecolumn = 0
```

Comment: Try to edit with SSMS instead of calling update in code. Right-click table `Tablexyz` - select `Edit Top 200 Rows` - change value of one row.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's unfortunate. That can't be expected behavior. I will update my post.

Comment: I was actually getting the same error on SSMS as well as code with one exception. The example on my original post failed on SSMS but works on code, but if I used a sub query on the insert like "INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] Select 123 Union All Select 456" then it failed on both SSMS and code. Adding the "SET NOCOUNT ON" statement fixed all the problems. Thanks.